# Ethernet module ENC28C60 doesn't connect to internet when DHCP on router is disabled

Tags: c++, networking, arduino

Using [this](https://github.com/jcw/ethercard) library I try to connect with static IP but it doesn't connect to internet. If DHCP is enabled on router and remove the `ether.staticSetup(myip, gwip, dnsip, netmask);` it works. I use arduino MEGA. Static IP is tested and working on other devices.

**Question**: How can I set correctly static ip?

Note: I post this question on this community because it's about code and not for electronics.

**Connections** :

```
VCC -   3.3V
GND -    GND 
SCK - Pin 52
SO  - Pin 50
SI  - Pin 51
CS  - Pin 53 # Selectable with the ether.begin() function
```

**Code**:

```
// This is a demo of the RBBB running as webserver with the Ether Card
// 2010-05-28 <jc@wippler.nl> http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

#include <EtherCard.h>

// ethernet interface mac address, must be unique on the LAN
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74, 0x69, 0x69, 0x2D, 0x30, 0x31 };
static byte myip[] = { xxx, xxx, 216, 203 };
static byte gwip[] = { xxx, xxx, 216, 126 };
static byte dnsip[] = { 8, 8, 8, 8};
static byte netmask[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0};
byte Ethernet::buffer[500];
BufferFiller bfill;

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 53) == 0)
    Serial.println(F("Failed to access Ethernet controller"));
  ether.staticSetup(myip, gwip, dnsip, netmask);

  while (ether.clientWaitingGw())
    ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());
  Serial.println("\nGateway found");
  Serial.print("ether.clientWaitingGw=");// just to test
  Serial.print(ether.clientWaitingGw());
}


void loop () {

  word len = ether.packetReceive();
  word pos = ether.packetLoop(len);

  if (pos) { // check if valid tcp data is received
    ether.httpServerReply(homePage());// send web page data
    Serial.println("\nSend web data");
  }
delay(1000);
}


static word homePage() {
  long t = millis() / 1000;
  word h = t / 3600;
  byte m = (t / 60) % 60;
  byte s = t % 60;
  bfill = ether.tcpOffset();
  bfill.emit_p(PSTR(
                 "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                 "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                 "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
                 "\r\n"
                 "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'/>"
                 "<title>RBBB server</title>"
                 "<h1>$D$D:$D$D:$D$D</h1>"),
               h / 10, h % 10, m / 10, m % 10, s / 10, s % 10);
  return bfill.position();
}
```

**Output**:

```
XXX.XXX.216.203
XXX.XXX.216.126
8.8.8.8
255.255.255.0

Gateway found
Fail to send web data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a research the delay on loop function is causing request timeout. By deleting `delay(1000);` it works

Correct code with static ip:

```
#include <EtherCard.h>

// ethernet interface mac address, must be unique on the LAN
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74, 0x69, 0x69, 0x2D, 0x30, 0x31 };
static byte myip[] = { xxx, xxx, 216, 203 };
static byte gwip[] = { xxx, xxx, 216, 126 };
static byte dnsip[] = { 8, 8, 8, 8};
static byte netmask[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0};
byte Ethernet::buffer[500];
BufferFiller bfill;

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 53) == 0)// 53 only on MEGA
    Serial.println(F("Failed to access Ethernet controller"));
  ether.staticSetup(myip, gwip, dnsip, netmask);

  while (ether.clientWaitingGw())
    ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());
  Serial.println("\nGateway found");
  Serial.print("ether.clientWaitingGw=");// just to test
  Serial.print(ether.clientWaitingGw());
}


void loop () {

  word len = ether.packetReceive();
  word pos = ether.packetLoop(len);

  if (pos) { // check if valid tcp data is received
    ether.httpServerReply(homePage());// send web page data
    Serial.println("\nSend web data");
  }
```